# php how to pass authorization bearer in unirest

Tags: php, laravel, header, authorization, unirest

i have unirest code running in laravel 4.2:
(doesn't work)

```
<?php
    $headers = array('Authorization', 'Bearer TOKENASDKASKDN231DAS2');
    $body    = array();
    $respons = Unirest\Request::get("https://api.request", $headers, $body);
?>
// and this
<?php
  Unirest\Request::auth('TOKENASDKASKDN231DAS2', '');
  $header  = array();
  $body    = array();
  $respons = Unirest\Request::get("https://api.request", $headers, $body);
?>
```

I tried running this in getpostman

URL: GET - https://api.request

HEADER: Authorization : Bearer TOKENASDKASKDN231DAS2

It actually works. Don't why not in unirest.

---

I already have a working code
with using the Auth Basic:

`Authorization: Basic c2tfdGVzdF9uNTA0OWFhNjA1M2M5YTAyMTdiZWE3ODA3MGZiZjUwMTo=`

in php:

`Unirest\Request::auth('c2tfdGVzdF9uNTA0OWFhNjA1M2M5YTAyMTdiZWE3ODA3MGZiZjUwMTo=', '');`

Comment: How does it not work? What behavior are you expecting and what behavior are you getting? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is simple.

This is correct, as you said: `Unirest\Request::auth('TOKEN HERE', '');`

This is not `$headers = array('Authorization', 'Bearer TOKENASDKASKDN231DAS2');`

Because `$headers` is getting an array,

> it should be `array('Authorization' => 'Bearer TOKENHERE');`

**DO NOT COMPARE HEADER and AUTH**

Comment: That was so stupid of me, it now works.. thanks for tracing that for me.